# wxpython event on deactivating a grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a window with two grids in it. Example for using:

Making some operations on grid1. When making operations on another object in this window(like the other grid) I want to do final operation on grid1. What is the right event for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use focus events. Either catch `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` which fires when you leave the grid widget or catch `wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS` when you enter a new widget. Then you can do something in your event handler to update grid1.